# For either Libreoffice or Word, how do I insert this kind of field?

Tags: ms-word, libreoffice

I am writing a play, and I want to be able to insert two fields, much like Page #. Let me explain...

Each time Scene 1, Scene 2, Scene 3, etc., I want the pages in that particular field to be named after it. So, Scene 2 would be 15 pages, and it would have a 2 on each of those pages. Then on Scene 3, it would have 20 pages, and I want each of those pages with a 3.

Also, I want to do this for Act I and II. For each page in Act I, I want the roman numeral I. For each page in Act II, I want the Roman numeral II.

I was wondering if there is a particular kind of code I can use in either Libreoffice or Word? For example, when "Scene 2" is detected by the software, it writes "2" on that pages and continues to repeat on each proceeding page, until it detects "Scene 3" and inserts 3, instead of 2, on the proceeding pages. I want do the same thing for Act I and Act II.

So basically, I want to insert fields for both of these. Thanks.

Comment: This question would be better suited for SuperUser (as it is not programming related). If you need a quick solution, googling your problem turns up thttp://word.mvps.org/faqs/numbering/chapternumber.htm. Keep a bookmark on this site an you will find many useful tips for your writing!

Comment: Use the "outline numbering" option in Libre Office. Then, use the "Insert > Fields" option if you wanted to insert these values like page numbers at the bottom of a page.

Comment: In Word I'd probably use a StyleRef field to "repeat" the number. And I'd create a character style to apply to the number, referencing that style name in the StyleRef field.